# Get only one result from search query REST API

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest, search-query

We are trying to get only one result from couple of results. Bellow is command:

```
_api/search/query?querytext='JobTitle="IT support"'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'
```

When I run it, I get couple of users with same job position. How can I get only one person from result?

At the end, my ultimate goal is to get account name of one of them.

*edit: it is querytext not queryproperty.*

Comment: So you have a set of results and you want a specific one? How do you know which one? Do you already have the wanted user? 

--> How about you search for the person you actually want? querytext='JobTitle="IT support" AND AccountName="TheUserYouwant"'

Comment: What is the logic determining which user you need to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='JobTitle="IT support"'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=1
```

Try this code

Comment: that's a negative. not working.

Comment: Strange, it should work. Check this -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx

`http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&rowlimit=30`

Check updated code.

Comment: as I can see I get only first user from list. I don't want first, I want one :) example 4th or 5th

Comment: how to determine which user you want ? You want to filter on something like last name or first name or a different property ?

Comment: as I wrote in question, final goal is to get his account name, I don't want to hardcode user's name or surname in url. what will happen tomorrow when that user goes out of company :)

Comment: @DaniloKorac So you get a set of users and you want for example the 4th or 5th? how do you know which one you want? your question is lacking that information.

Comment: @DaniloKorac - the user at 4th or 5th position wont be permanent, as there could be changes to search index so the position might change or as you mentioned user leaves the org. So you will need additional filter on it.